# How to select an element that has focus on it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, focus, css-selectors

How can you select an element that has current focus?

There is no `:focus` filter in jQuery, that is why we can use something like this:

```
$('input:focus').someFunction();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do so I can know if there is a better approach

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: Note that you can use `$(':focus')` to find the element currently focused in the current document.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Really the best way to do it is to setup a handler for the onFocus event, and then set a variable to the ID of the element that has focus.

something like this:

```
var id;

$(":input").focus(function () {
     id = this.id;
});
```

Comment: Why $(this).attr('id') use this.id

Comment: Becareful because the window can also receive focus, which means this code won't work as expected in all cases.

Comment: IS window an input? This code says select only input elements. so window does not fire callback.

Comment: Sam Shiles answer seems to be the best by far.

Comment: Did not work (for me), use Sams or Marcus answer below instead.

Comment: Maybe at the time this answers was ok, but not anymore.

Answer (score 153):

`$(document.activeElement)` will return the currently focused element and is faster than using the pseudo selector :focus.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: *this* should be the chosen answer. no DOM traversal and much faster than any of the other solutions offered here.

Comment: This is the right answer.  jQuery docs even say not to use the :focus pseudo-selector when you just want the currently selected element.

Comment: Yes, even the jquery documentation recommends this method over the pseudo query.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Chrome. When I click on an element using this in Opera I am getting the id properly. But in Chrome im getting blank. The other solution above does the same thing though, so this is still the best solution.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work in chrome, it always returns body.

Answer (score 123):

```
alert($("*:focus").attr("id"));
```

I use jQuery.

It will alert id of element is focusing.

I hope it useful for you.

Comment: From what I can gather, support for the `:focus` filter has been added to jquery since the OP asked this question, so this answer is now valid.

Comment: Performance is poor, use document.activeElement whenever possible.

Comment: jesus - you are really using * as a selector? you know that * selects _ALL_ elements? every td in every damned table. 93 upvotes?

Comment: Sam Shiles answer, suggesting use of $(document.activeElement), is a better solution.  Straight from the jQuery docs page on the :focus pseudo-selector: "If you are looking for the currently focused element, $( document.activeElement ) will retrieve it without having to search the whole DOM tree."

Comment: @kingjeffrey, it's perfect only if you don't know how poor it's!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    focused: function(elem) { return elem.hasFocus; }
});

alert($('input :focused').length);
```

Comment: `document.hasFocus()` does exist, but such a method or attribute is not available for elements. Tried in Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 5):

If you use JQuery, you can write a [selector like this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/focus-selector-filter):

```
$.expr[':'].focus = function(a){ return (a == document.activeElement); }
```

You can then select the currently focused element: `$(":focus")`

Not only form controls can have focus. Any html element with a tabindex can be focused in modern browsers.

Comment: What is the performance of this like? Also $(".:focus") appears to be already implemented by jQuery 1.7.3. It at least works fine without your implementation for me.

Answer (score 4):

Lifted from the examples for the current jQuery version (1.7) docs:

```
$(elem).is(":focus");
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking element has focus or not.

```
if ($("...").is(":focus")) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CoffeeScript version of it. Based upon jmanrubia's code:

`$.expr[':'].focus = (a) ->
  a is document.activeElement`

You would also call it like so `$(".:focus")`