# Writing value on the current textbox - Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Well I'm facing an issue here:
I use Selenium to automate test on my application, and I use the following code to fill a textbox:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("form_widget_serial_number").send_keys("example", u'\u0009')
```

All the textboxes have the same id (form_widget_serial_number) so it's impossible to select a specific textbox by using selection by id (the code above selects the first textbox and  **u'\u0009'** changes the cursor position to the next textbox).

[image]

Anyway, how can I send values to the "current" textbox without using ***find_element_by_id*** or another selector, given that the cursor is in the current textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several selectors available to you - Xpath and css in particular are very powerful.

Xpath can even select by the text of an element and then access its second sibling<sup>1</sup>:

```
elem = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(), 'match this text')]/following-sibling::*[2]")
```

If you need to find the current element that has focus:

```
focused_elem = driver.switch_to.active_element
```

And then to find the next one:

```
elem_sibling = focused_elem.find_element(:xpath, "following-sibling::*")
```

Using this example, you could easily traverse any sequence of sequential elements, which would appear to solve your problem.

Take a close look at the structure of the page and then see how you would navigate to the element you need from a reference you *can* get to. There is probably an Xpath or css selector that can make the traversal across the document.

<sup>1</sup> FYI, I'm using an old version of Selenium in Ruby, in case your version's syntax is different

Comment: Yes I knew all of the selectors :) . I just wanted something like "find next" as you mentioned above, without finding by specific labels (eg id, xpath, css, text). I'll try your approach soon.

Comment: Updated answer to include getting element that currently has focus - selection can be done completely without referencing id, class, or text.

Comment: I didn't even try the xpath stuff you mentioned above.
focused_elem = self.driver.switch_to_active_element() and focused_elem.send_keys("example", u'\u0009') do the iteration I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

1. Get a list of all contemplable elements by the known id
2. Loop over them until you find a focused element
3. Use send_keys to write into that element

To get the focused element something like

```
get_element_index('dom=document.activeElement')
```

might work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659818/how-do-i-test-which-element-has-the-focus-in-selenium-rc) for more information.

Edit: If the list you get from 1. is accidently sorted properly the index of an element in this list might even represent the number of *u'\u0009'* you have to send to reach that specific element.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ActionChains** utility to do that. Use following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).send_keys("Hello").perform()
```