# focusout but only if not focussed into another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-focusout

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        $("#divCompany1").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#Button1").focusout(function () {
        $("#divCompany1").slideUp("fast");
    });

    $("#divCompany1").focusout(function () {

        $("#divCompany1").slideUp("fast");

    });

});
```

The following is a description of what I want to happen:

- If the user focuses on Button1 but then loses focus I want divCompany1 to slide
- If the user focuses on divCompany1 but then loses focus I want divCompany1 to slide up only
- The exception to the above is if Button1 loses focus but divCompany1 gains it at the same time I want nothing to happen

This basically allows the user to go between Button1 and divCompany1 without divCompany1 sliding.

I've searched around for a while and not found anything of use, I'm thinking theres likely a need for a flag or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I seem to have solved it:

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
        $("#divCompany1").slideToggle("fast");
        $("#<%=lstBoxCompany.ClientID%>").focus();
    });

    $("#divCompany1").focusout(function () {
        $("#divCompany1").slideUp("fast");
    });
```

Instead of worrying about focusout for `Button1` I simply set the focus to the element I wanted to user to go to (`divCompany1`) and only after this focus has gone do I hide it.

Works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

This question says how to detect if an element has focus: [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Then all you need to do is:

```
$("#Button1").focusout(function () {
    if (!$("#divCompany1").is(":focus")) {
        $("#divCompany1").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: This causes an exception here `if (!$("#divCompany1").is(":focus")) {`