# hiding div if clicked anywhere in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

[image]

I have a a textbox in my app, `onkeyup` I show a div that gets result from database. so whenever user enters something I show the div, the problem is that I want to hide the div if users clicks somewhere else in the DOM.
just like when you select a drop down if you click somewhere else the drop down is closed.
Is there any builtin mechanism for this in jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "body" ).click(function() {
  $( "#yourDivIdHere" ).hide();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I have some elements on div too, If someone click on BODY, it hides the div. if someone clicks on elements inside the div, it also hides the div

Comment: Then change `body` to whichever element you want. You can create a `<button>` somewhere in the DOM and change to `$("button")`. Alternatively, give your element an ID and use `$("#ElementIdHere")`.

Comment: didn't get that at all

Comment: @user1765876 give the div you want to hide an id `<div id="hideme">` and then use `$("#hideme")`

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and check the originator of a click event. Something like:

```
$('body').on('click',function (e) {
  var origin = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (/* [origin.id != your dropdowndiv.id] */) {
     /* hide your dropdowndiv */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Demo: http://jsbin.com/xatanicu/4/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').focusout(function() {
        $(document).click(function(e) {
            var targetId = $(e.target)[0].id;
            if((targetId !== 'hide-div')) {
                $('div').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what if the input is a button?

Comment: focusout works if I click on any other area, but If I click on the div , it still hides the div then.

Comment: just see this http://jsbin.com/xatanicu/5/edit , click on the button, 2- click somewhere else, 3- click on button again, it wont show the div, as it was showing in step 1

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the result div when the textbox loses focus:

```
//vanilla JavaScript
textBoxId.onblur = divId.style.display = 'none';

//jQuery
$("#textBoxId").blur(function() {
  $("#divId").hide();
});
```

UPDATE:
It should not hide the result div if the user clicked on the result div itself. (The answer is based on [Action on blur except when specific element clicked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901899/action-on-blur-except-when-specific-element-clicked-with-jquery))

```
var keepFocus = false;
function hideList(){
    if(!keepFocus){
        $('#divId').hide();
    }
}

$('#textBoxId').blur(function() {
    keepFocus = false;
    window.setTimeout(hideList, 100);
}).focus(function(){
    keepFocus = true;
});


$('#divId').blur(function() {
    keepFocus = false;
    window.setTimeout(hideList, 100);
}).click(function(){
    keepFocus = true;
});
```

See this solution in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/XC2D7/

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that not only it works by clicking somewhere but it also works if user leaves the textBox by pressing 'Tab' on the keyboard.

Comment: If you are using jQuery yes. I added the jQuery code as well.

Comment: @sap blur works if I click on any other area, but If I click on the div , it also hides the div then..