# jQuery: is an element in focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

I have an input element, and I'd like to ask if it is currently in focus without modifying what is already in focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be tricky to determine sometimes, but here is an answer that should help:

[Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)