# How to get input has focus or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get input tag of html has focus or not using jquery

keydown event will work for form if input,image etc. tag has focus. but it will not work it focus is on form but not on any tags like input,image etc.
How can I solve this.
Please help
Thanks in advance

`$('#title').focusout(function()` 
`{`
`if($(document.activeElement).is(":focus"))`
`{`
`alert('focus');`
`}`
`else`
`{`
`alert('not focus');`
`}`
`});`
// this will not work

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Answer (score 8):

you can do it by

```
if ($("#id").is(":focus")) {
  alert('focus');
}
```

Comment: $('#title').focusout(function() 
    {
     if($("#MakeTicket/title").is(":focus"))
     {
      alert('focus');
     }
     else
     {
      alert('not focus');
     }

     $('#Department').focus();
     return false;
    });

Comment: $('#title').focusout(function() 
    {
     if($("#MakeTicket/title").is(":focus"))
     {
      alert('focus');
     }
     else
     {
      alert('not focus');
     }

     $('#Department').focus();
     return false;
    }); but this will not work. anything wrong in my code

Comment: Doesn't work for dynamic elements added to the DOM after runtime...

Answer (score 3):

Its much easier to check by using jquery.
Using jquery u can do it like this

```
if($"#div/inputtocheck").is(":focus"))
{
//do something u want if it is in focus
}
```

The `:focus`  returns true if the div is in foucs and false if it is not in focus

Comment: $('#title').focusout(function() { if($("#MakeTicket/title").is(":focus")) { alert('focus'); } else { alert('not focus'); } $('#Department').focus(); return false; }); but this will not work. anything wrong in my code

Comment: I cant understand ur code here please post an edit in ur question. This will make ur code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.activeElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#document-level-focus-apis).

Comment: I have tried with this, but this will also not work

Comment: That is what jQuery uses, I suggested it because it's a lot more efficient to use than a jQuery object and selector. If you can't get it to work directly, then jQuery can't help. *document.activeElement* is part of the W3C [Element Traversal Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/), which is reasonably new so some browsers do not support it.