# How to test elemnt has focus or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to get input has focus or not using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703862/how-to-get-input-has-focus-or-not-using-jquery)
>   [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Hi i want to test Input tag has focus or not using jquery

`if(document.getElementById('Department').focus())`

I am using. but it will not work it will always give me false.
Please help me to solve this

Comment: Didn't you already ask this earlier today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703862/how-to-get-input-has-focus-or-not-using-jquery

Comment: if you're using jQuery you can use `$('#Department')` instead of `document.getElementById('Department')` see http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ and the other selectors.

Comment: Yes i have asked same question.

Comment: @Roayl: Your question is being closed *for a reason*. It's already been asked, and answered, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus If the community closes your question, don't re-post it. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

i think you may be able to use the following code

```
document.activeElement
```

Comment: No. I want to test multiple elements by using document.getElementById

Comment: Then you can test each one with *document.activeElement*. But only one (if any) can have focus at at time, so just get document.activeElement and see if it's one of the elements you wish to test using the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#Department").is(":focus")) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

The `:focus` selector only matches elements that currently have focus. You can read more about it in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/). The `is` function tests the set of matched elements against a selector, and returns true if any of them match.

Comment: I have tried with this, but this will not work