# jQuery events; prevent "siblings" from triggering each others events

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Using **jQuery 1.6.1**, given I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="control">
    <label>My Control</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

When an `<input>` in `<div class="control">` (*hereafter only `control`*) is focused, the `<label>` (*with `position: relative;`*) animates:

```
$('.control :input').bind('focus', function(e){
    $(this).prevAll('label').animate({
        'left': '-50px'
    }, 250);
});
```

And when blurred, the `<label>` returns:

```
.bind('blur', function(e){
    $(this).prevAll('label').animate({
        'left': '0px'
    }, 250);
});
```

However, if one of the `<input>` elements gains focus, and then blurs as focus is switched to another `<input>` within the same `control` (*via <kbd>Tab</kbd> or mouse click*) the events of course still fire, and the `<label>` animates back and forth.

How can I force the blur event to trigger only when focus is lost from **all** inputs within a given `control`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated the answer based on more inputs provided by the OP.

If a slight delay of one second to hide the label is  fine then you can use setTimeout/clearTimeout combination..
Something like:

```
<div class="control">
    <label>My Control</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="control">
    <label>My Control</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="control">
    <label>My Control</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="control">
    <label>My Control</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var timeoutIds = [];
            $('.control').each(function(index, el){
                $(':input', el).bind('focus', function(e){     
                        clearTimeout(timeoutIds[index]);
                        $(this).prevAll('label').animate({        
                                'left': '-50px'     
                        }); 
                });

                $(':input', el).bind('blur', function(e){     
                        var that = this;
                        timeoutIds[index] = setTimeout(function(){
                            $(that).prevAll('label').animate({        
                                    'left': '0px' 
                            }); 
                    }, 500);
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tn9sV/2/

Comment: Thanks @Cybernate - Almost works like a charm. Perhaps it's my fault, as I failed to mention there will be more than one `control`. When switching from `control` to `control`, the blur fails to trigger on the first because of the `clearTimeout()` called on the second.

Comment: @Tomcat: But the blur is first triggered and then the focus on the second.

Comment: Thanks, but no @Cybernate, sorry it doesn't. This is what I meant http://jsfiddle.net/Tn9sV/1/ Any idea?

Comment: Working off your answer directly, I'd have to assign (*and manage*) an array of timeoutIds, perhaps assigning them to the given `control` elements as arbitrary `data()`, but that seems like an awful lot of overhead for something misleadingly simple.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: I see what you mean by multiple controls. Let me see if there is any simple alternative

Comment: @TomcatExodus let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1714/discussion-between-cybernate-and-tomcatexodus)

Comment: Awesome @Cybernate - That works spectacularly. Thanks so much again for your persistence; very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your blur callback I would look at something like the `:focus` selector that was introduced in 1.6:

[Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

If `$('.control :focus).length > 0` then `return` the function to stop it from running.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mcp - Unfortunately, it appears (*in my cursory testing*) that the blur event fires immediately prior to the next focus event, even when switching immediately from `input` to `input`; it always evaluates to 0.

Comment: Aaah, interesting. I think a slight delay would be in order then, according to the other answers. Give the focus a chance to register, then evaluate if there is a :focused element or not.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm hoping the answer @Cybernate proposed will get me there.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved something similar in the past by binding a new focus to the document or to the form instead and having that trigger the label to come back, instead of binding a blur to the inputs.

Comment: Thanks @citizen conn - This seems like a viable solution, however I can't seem to bind a `focus` event to `body`, `document`, `window`, etc. What element specifically did you attach the event handler to?

Comment: @TomcatExodus Sorry, bind a mousedown event, not focus

Comment: Thanks @citizen conn - Problem is though, if I `Tab` out of the control group, it won't trigger.

Comment: @TomcatExodus GP... then you could bind focus events to the following and previous fields. the plot thickens, I know, but otherwise it might call for more insane js instead of just jquery event handling.

Answer (score 1):

In `blur` callback you can detect if any input element is focused now using this `$("input:focus").length`. If `length>0` than do not animation

**Update**

What about this code?

```
    var control;
    var inTheSameControl=false;
    $('.control :input').bind('focus', function(e){
        if(control)
        {
            if(control.find(this).length>0)
                inTheSameControl=true;
            else
                inTheSameControl=false;
        }
        control=$(this).parent();
        if(!inTheSameControl)
        {
            console.log('focus');
        }
    });
    $('.control :input').bind('blur', function(e){
        if(!inTheSameControl)
        {
            console.log('blur');
        }
    });
```

It works with multiple `div.control`
When you are switching focus to the `input` in another `.contor`, text 'focus' logs into console, if you are staying in the same `.control` - doesn't. 
Instead of `console.log(...)` you may write what you want. I haven't written your code(animation) because it is not the subject.

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan Polutsygan - Unfortunately it does not work, refer to my comment on Alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

- Option 1 (using current scheme):

  - blur: .delay your animation by a fraction of a second
  - focus: .stop your existing animation
- Option 2 (change blur item):

  - chage the blur item to be on your div instead of the label