# ajax replace content lose focus on text box

Tags: ajax

I don't even know if this is possible but here is an example:

```
<div id="register">
//bunch of markup including inputs
</div>
```

Via AJAX I replace the register div, but if there is a focus on a text box inside of the register div, it loses focus when replaces happens. Is there a way to maintain focus?

here is the javascript:

```
$("#cart_contents input").change(function()
{
    $(this.form).ajaxSubmit({target: "#register_container", success: function()
    {

    }
    });
});
```

I have lots of inputs inside this form, how can I figure out how to refocus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get an `ID` handle for the text box, e.g. `textbox`, when AJAX is complete, call:

```
$('#textbox').focus();
```

**A more generic solution**. Given focusable elements have `ID`s, bookend your AJAX stuff like so:

```
var focusedId = $(document.activeElement).attr('id');

// .. AJAX, replacement ..

$('#' + focusedId).focus();
```

Reference [focus()<sup>jQuery</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/focus/), [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus).

Comment: I added some example javascript...How would I be able to do this?

Comment: @ChrisMuench see my update. you could bookend your `$(this.form).ajaxSubmit(..);` with above.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the markups inside the register div,the focus from earlier fields would be removed,use

```
$("#"+someid).focus();
```

to focus on the textfields with id if you are using jquery..

Comment: I added some example javascript...How would I be able to do this?

Comment: `var innerid = document.activeElement.id; `// to get inner element id with focus before ajax call .
//in ajax call successs function:
`$("#"+innerid).focus();`