# Lose focus of select-option when rebuilding option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically setting the options of my select-fields. Every time the form changes, new data is received from a Servlet and the current selections are overwritten.

Problem here is, that if I select an option, the form loads the javascript function, and I loose my selection / focus.

```
var capacityOptionsAsString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < capacityArray.length; i++) {
  capacityOptionsAsString += "<option value='" + capacityArray[i] + "'>" + capacityArray[i] + "</option>";
  console.log('capacity option: ' + capacityOptionsAsString);
}
$("select[name='inptCapacity']").find('option').remove().end().append($(capacityOptionsAsString));
```

Any idea how to keep the selection?

---

**Edit**: Maybe I was not clear enough. I want to keep the selection. So it has to be validated, if the option is selected, if it is, we have to select it again.

Comment: what do you mean by 'form loads the javascript function'?

Comment: $('form[name="formName"] :input').change(function() {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the focus again:

```
$("select[name='inptCapacity']").focus();
```

**Update**

get selected option:

```
var selected_value = $("select[name='inptCapacity'] option:selected").val()
```

Do your changes

```
$("select[name='inptCapacity']").find('option').remove().end().append($(capacityOptionsAsString));
```

Select it again:

```
$('select[name='inptCapacity'] option[value="' + selected_value + "]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

You totally need an id for your select ;)

Comment: and how do I find out if the focus is currently set?

Comment: `$("select[name='inptCapacity']").is(":focus")` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: @dooonot `$(...).is(':focus')`

Comment: Sorry guys, seems like we mix focus and select. I need to know which option is selected.

Comment: Can you tell me how this should be integrated into my example above? I think we need to compare the values of the selected option with the value in the for-loop and if it is equal, we set it as selected?

Comment: Thanks a lot PiTheNumber, much appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. By the way @doonot.com: Tiny font, but nice webpage! I like the design.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="inptCapacity"]').is(':focus');

$('form[name="formName"] :input').change(function() {

   // keep the select focus always on input change

   $('select[name="inptCapacity"]').focus(); 

});
```