# Detect if input has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of my web app's page consists of a grid and a search box. I capture the keypress event to select through each of the grid's rows using the space bar. However, this creates a problem for when someone wants to look up a phrase in the search box.

I know that jQuery has a `.focus` method to bind an event handler to an input or give focus to an element. But how do I get a boolean value to determine if the search input has focus or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
if ($("#id").is(":focus")) {
  alert('focus');
}
```

you can find more info on below link :

[Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Answer (score 2):

Like so?

```
if($('...').is(':focus')){

}
```

Comment: I know. I would've had it by 2 minutes but StackOverflow didn't think I was human :-(

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
$(this).is(":focus");
```