# Check textbox focus using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

I need to check if a particular textbox has the focus or not using jQuery. So my code is like this, but it is not working:

```
if (document.getElementById("lastname").focus = true) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

My use-case is this: I have a textbox which should be shown or hidden when the `#lastname` textbox gains or loses focus. However, if the `#lastname` textbox loses the focus to the other textbox, the latter should remain visible until it loses focus as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: p.s. to check equality in JavaScript, the operator is `==`; a single `=` is used to assign the value of the RHS to the variable on the LHS, which you definitely don't want in this case.

Comment: Your code is NOT Jquery... :|

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if ($("#lastname").is(':focus')) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

[jQuery docs for `:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) 
[jQuery docs for `.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

---

**Update:**
To show/hide an element when the field gains/loses focus use the `focusin` and `focusout` events handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lastname').focusin(function() {
        $(hidden-element).show();
    }).add(hidden-element).focusout(function() {
        if ( !$(hidden-element).is(':focus') ) {
            $(hidden-element).hide();
        }
    });
});
//where hidden-element is a reference to or selector for your hidden text field
```

Comment: Code is fine.But i apologize for not telling the actual requirements.Actually its a textbox which gets hide or show when focus is in or out on a another textfield.Now when the focus is out,the second appeared texbox also gets hide.it should be hide only when the focus is out from both the textboxes.

Comment: @user853575 OK I understand your requirement now, you only want to hide the `hidden-element` if it is not in focus. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#lastname").focus(function(){
    alert("lastname has focus");
});
```

Comment: please read the jquery docs before u go further with this: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Ok.Thanks.Actually i am making a other textfield visible when focus is on the "lastname" field.it is working now.But when focus is not on "lastname",that field still appears.it should be hidden then.

Comment: @user853575 It's usually a good idea to edit your question directly and include any updates or pertinent info. Anyway, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.getElementById("lastname").focus == true) {
        alert("hello");
    }
```

Check with == , using = is an assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery's [:focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector. Or you can always add a class and check for that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function check() {

        if ($(document.activeElement).attr("id") === "element_name") {
            alert('checkbox is focused');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var status = $('#lastname').is(":focus");
alert(status);//false or true
```