# Is :focus return always false

Tags: jquery

I creating a script, and I like to know if a scecific field is focused by using the following code:

```
console.log($('#element_title').is(':focus'));
```

The problem is that either the field is focus or not, I always get "false" as result. Am I doing something wrong with that ?

The element I try to check is a text field.

---

The problem solved, with the reccomendation of the "adeneo".

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `if (document.activeElement.id == 'element_title') {...}`

Comment: What do you do to trigger the check? If, for example, you're clicking a button to do so then you're removing focus from the input (and focusing the button instead).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UWv9r/1/show/ can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: [There is a similar existing post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
$('#element_title').focus(function()
{
console.log('I have the focus now!');
});
```