# How do I get active element class with Jquery if it's dynamic

Tags: jquery, dynamic, textinput

When I try to get the active element in javascript (`document.activeElement.tagName`), it keeps returning `BODY`. The input element was created with jquery.

Here's the situation:
On page load, I created an input box via jquery. (standard class, dynamic id)

on a button click, I want to test if that input box is selected

Thanks for the help

Comment: you want to check if the text box is focus?

Comment: something like this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.activeElement` returns the currently focused element. When there is no focused element, the active one is the page's `body`.

When you click `button`, the textbox no longer has the focus, so the body element is always returned.

See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep track of the last selected item by monitoring which one was clicked on last.

The following script should accomplish what you're looking for.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgYp2/1/)

**JS**

```
$('body').append(
  //Dynamic Inputs being added
  $('<input />', { 'id':'test', 'type':'text'})
).append(
  //Dynamic Inputs being added
  $('<input />', { 'id':'test2', 'type':'text'})
).on('click', 'input[type="text"]', function(e){
  //Keep track of the last selected input
  $('.lastSelected').removeClass('lastSelected'); 
  $(this).addClass('lastSelected'); 
}); 

//Get the last selected input from the page on a button click
$('#mybutton').click(function(e){
  var items = $('.lastSelected')
  if(items.length > 0){
    alert($('.lastSelected').attr('id')); 
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id='mybutton' type='button' value='Click Me' />
```