# Focusout if not elements is clicked (see fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, jquery-click-event, jquery-focusout

I have an "clear"-icon dynamically showing up in my input-field when I write something. Keypress and focus events handle that well, the only thing is that I want the icon to be removed when the input field is not in focus mode. The problem is that I have a click event on the icon, so if I click the icon, the focusout-event fires. I can't figure it out.

```
$(".searchInput").focusout(function(e) {
    console.log(e);

    if(e.currentTarget != this) {
        if ($(".keypress").length > 0) {
            $(".keypress").remove();
        }
    }
})
```

I've put together a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9RbW/.

As you can see, if the input value isn't empty, the icon is still there, I don't know how to check if it's being clicked, or something like that...

Comment: I don't see an icon anywhere in the fiddle...

Comment: Hmm, a black little box should appear to the side of the input field if you type something in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as you know) is that the clear icon is getting removed before its click event is fired when you focus-out from the text-box. One possible solution is altering the opacity of the clear icon instead of removing it, so that it still continues to receive events.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/w9RbW/10/

```
// Have the clear icon in there all the time
$("<span class='keypress'><i class='icon-remove-sign'></i></span>").appendTo($(".searchInput").parent()); 

$(".keypress").click(function(e) {
  if($(this).css('opacity') == 0) return;
  $(".searchInput").val("").focus();
  $(this).css('opacity', '0'); // hide it after clearing the text
})

// focusout
$(".searchInput").blur(function(e) {
  $(".keypress").css('opacity', '0'); // hide it on blur
})

$(".searchInput").focus(function() {
  if ($(".searchInput").val() != "") {
    $(".keypress").css('opacity', '1'); // show it
  }
})

$(".searchInput").keyup(function() {
  if($(this).val() != "") {
    $(".keypress").css('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    $(".keypress").css('opacity', '0');
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, therefore I thought you could just check perhaps whether the icon is hovered or something. This solution works, but you can still click and erase.

Comment: Code slightly modified so as to negate the click if the icon is not visible. Check the updated answer and demo.

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems more user-friendly, especially when it's going to be used on smartphones with all the clumsy fingers. This was my thought at first too, but It'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this  http://jsfiddle.net/w9RbW/8/

If you only want to remove icon when not in focus.

```
    $(".searchInput").focusout(function(e) {
  $(".keypress").css('opacity', '0');
        if(e.currentTarget != this) {
            if ($(".keypress").length > 0) {
                $(".keypress").remove();
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Yes, that I do know. But the "clear"-icon should be clickable and clear the input field, maybe I wasn't so clear on that. So, this should work, but also the click event.

Comment: Nope. The icon should Never be visible if the input doesn't have focus, or if there isn't anything written.

Comment: adding $(".keypress").css('opacity', '0'); will do the work
see edit

Comment: No, this is the same thing as before, now you can't click the icon, because the focusout fires before and hides it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set a timer for checking every 10 seconds whether 'clear' icon is there or not! Once you have found that textbox has lost focus, then you can remove that clear icon and stop that timer

[Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Comment: Sounds like a detour, I should be able to just remove it if I don't click the icon, somehow.

Comment: Yes, ideally clear icon should be removed on 'blur' or 'onmouseout' event.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can set/remove some flag on icon mouseover/out and check it in focusout event.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I follow, perhaps you can give me an example? The fiddle is in the question.