# Jquery if input not focused not working

Tags: jquery, input, focus

i binded some keys via .keypress() but they should not be binded if one of my input fields is focused so I googled a bit and found that [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I don't get this working.

-> http://jsfiddle.net/DzAwn/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (!($("input").is(":focus"))) {
    alert('not focused');
}
```

});

There should be a workaround with variables and .focus(), but I think the way I tried is the easiest, if it's working....

Need your help! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DzAwn/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include jQuery (upper select box in left sidebar). It should work then.

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid. But I just figured out that I need to use .focus() and .blur() to set a boolean variable. Because I need to get it checked all the time and in the example on top it only gets checked once... that was stupid... sorry =/