# Javascript/jQuery detect if input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I detect when `.click` event triggers if textarea is already focused?

I have this jquery:

```
$(".status").on("click","textarea",function(){
        if ($(this) == "focused") {
            // fire this step
        }else{
            $(this).focus();
            // fire this step
    }
```

Comment: its not a duplicate because the other question asks specifically for a jquery solution.

Comment: I agree. I wonder if the OP used to be jQuery-based...

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson And so implicitly does this, since the code provided uses jQuery (as it did when originally posted). Thus it **is** a duplicate.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

With pure javascript:

```
this === document.activeElement // where 'this' is a dom object
```

or with jquery's `:focus` pseudo selector.

```
$(this).is(':focus');
```

Comment: I don't know why it is not working.... none of them.. if it's not focused it fires the first step.. but it should fire the else step..

Comment: Clicking the textarea will alway focus it.

Comment: Note that setting focus with 'focus()' won't work if the node isn't attached to the dom or is hidden (e.g. display:none;)

Comment: thank you for not bringing a jQuery solution. Especially because the pure JS solution is so much shorter too. *tips hat*

Comment: @Mathias - You are probably referring to some obscure definition of 'shorter'...

Comment: @katzenhut ha, yeah ... not sure what I was trying to say (back in 2014). I assume I meant 'shorter' as in, doesn't invoke a bunch of library code?!

Comment: Seems there's now a :focus pseudo-selector.  So `document.querySelector('textarea:focus')` will return the textarea element that is in focus, or the usual `null` if there isn't one.

Comment: The above seems to work on Chrome, but if you're developing with Cordova, you might find this doesn't work on iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use JQuery, then using the [**JQuery :focus selector**](https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) will do the needful

```
$(this).is(':focus');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's [**.is( ":focus" )**](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

```
$(".status").on("click","textarea",function(){
        if ($(this).is( ":focus" )) {
            // fire this step
        }else{
                    $(this).focus();
            // fire this step
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$(this).is(':focus');
```

Take a look at [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus) it features some more examples