# Check if an input field has focus in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus

Using jQuery, I can test if an input field has focus like so:

```
if ($("...").is(":focus")) {
    ...
}
```

How do I do that without using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript detect if input is focused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614844/javascript-detect-if-input-is-focused)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This question was answered here: [Javascript detect if input is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614844/javascript-detect-if-input-is-focused)

Taken from the above answer:

```
this === document.activeElement // where 'this' is a dom object
```

Comment: Example of use: `if (document.activeElement.tagName === "INPUT") console.log("An input is focused");`