# How to check if element has focused child using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I'm trying to remove all jQuery from my code. Until now I used

```js
if ($(selector).find(':focus').length === 0) {
    // focus is outside of my element
} else {
    // focus is inside my element
}
```

to distinguish wether the focus **is inside of one of my elements**. Can you show me a jQuery-free way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript detect if input is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614844/javascript-detect-if-input-is-focused)

Comment: It is not. Please read my question

Comment: [`ancestorElement:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)?

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).some(node => node.contains(document.activeElement))` maybe.

Comment: @FelixKling : Perfect. I think this is the solution, that i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Actually using `:focus` or `:focus-within` is better and easier.

Answer (score 102):

You can use [`Node.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) native DOM method for this.

```
el.contains(document.activeElement);
```

will check if `activeElement` is a descendant of `el`.
If you have multiple elements to check, you can use a `some` function to iterate.

Answer (score 33):

It is possible with Element's matches() method and with a simple selector string as follows:

```
let hasFocused = elem.matches(':focus-within:not(:focus)');
let focusedOrHasFocused = elem.matches(':focus-within');
```

Comment: This one is really precise and simple. The only drawback is probably lack of IE <9 support, which is quite acceptable nowadays.

Answer (score 9):

Use CSS [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class in `querySelectorAll()`

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  if (document.querySelectorAll("div :focus").length === 0)
    console.log("not focused");
  else
    console.log("focused")
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you put it inside a setTimeout? Thanks!

Comment: @carl-johan.blomqvist It is just for better understanding! For testing code you need to focus/unfocus on input. So timeout return response after 2 seconds

Comment: Maybe your example could use a different id than `div`, that was a bit confusing

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your situation, using events might be more performant.

You can use the [`focusin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event) and [`focusout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) events in that case.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("myEl");
el.addEventListener("focusin", () => console.log("focus!"));
el.addEventListener("focusout", () => console.log("blur!"));
```

Note that during `focusout` events the `document.activeElement` will be the document body. To work around this issue, you can make use of [`FocusEvent.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget).

Answer (score 6):

If you have issue where `document.activeElement` is returning `<body>` element **after blur event**, you just need to wrap it with setTimeout() and it will return correct element.

```
handleBlur() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log(document.activeElement); // this actually return active/focused element
    });
}
```

if you are using it standalone without timeout

```
handleBlur() {
    console.log(document.activeElement); // this is returning <body> element
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Combined some of answers posted here. Using a combination of [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event), [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event), [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) and [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget), you should be able to know when focus is on the children of a particular element.

```js
const elm = document.getElementById('check-focus-here')
elm.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target, event.relatedTarget)
  // console.log(elm.contains(event.relatedTarget))
})

elm.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target, event.relatedTarget)
  console.log(elm.contains(event.relatedTarget))
})
```

```css
#check-focus-here {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="check-focus-here">
  <input id="first-name" type="text" />
  <input id="middle-name" type="text" />
  <input id="last-name" type="text" />
  <button type="button">Save Name</button>
</div>

<button type="button">Tab to this for outside focus</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these existing non CSS based solutions account for the situation where the JavaScript context does not match the frame the node was rendered in. To account for this you would want to do something like the following:

```js
el.contains(el.ownerDocument.activeElement)
```

Comment: Please, when answering old questions with upvoted answers, elaborate a bit. In particular, how is this different from the most upvoted (and almost identical) answer?

Comment: The answer is that it accounts for situations where `el` might be in an iframe or a different window than the current `window`.  This is something you need to watch out for when developing for the Obsidian desktop app, for example.  There, `document` is always the main window, but your code needs to work even if it's dealing with elements in another window.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example following @Northern and @Adam Šipický answers...

```
const tr = document.querySelector("table tbody tr");

tr.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!tr.contains(document.activeElement)) {
      // Execute your condition code here...
    }
  }, 200);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 you can probably avoid javascript altogether to check if an element or any of the element's child nodes have focus – unless you are manipulating DOM elements outside of a parent element.

For example:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>foo</button>
  <button>food</button>
  <button>foosh</button>
</div>
```

```css
.parent { background: white }
.parent:focus-within { background: red }
.parent:focus-within button:not(:focus) { opacity: .5 }
```

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the selected element you can use:

```
let activeElement = document.activeElement
```

To check a specific element:

```
let elem = document.getElementById('someId');

let isFocused = (document.activeElement === elem);
```

Comment: I know this. But this solves not my problem. I want to know, if the active element is somewhere inside my element.

Comment: You can get the element via `getElementById ` and check if this is the `activeElement`. Added to my answer. @MarcGerritLanger