# How to check if a dom element is focusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Many DOM elements are focusable: divs with tabIndex, input elements, etc. Is there any simple way to check whether an element is focusable than checking a zillion of different cases? Is there a jQuery method for this?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2684561/1725764

Comment: @HashemQolami, that's not what he asked for.

Comment: And I didn't say that is!, I just asked a question.

Comment: Why is this question a duplicate?! The OP _doesn't care_ about all the elements on a page that are focusable, which is what the question linked to at the top seems to answer. The OP simply wants to find out whether a given dom element can receive focus. Very different questions both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer "translated" from here: [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus/1600194#1600194)

- `<a>` or `<area>` with `href`
- Any form elements which aren't disabled
- iframes
- Any element with `tabindex`

Additionaly, I believe that hidden elements can't get focus also.

Assuming that conditions, the following function may help you (assuming it'll always receive an jQuery element):

```
function canFocus( $el ) {
    if ( $el.is( ":hidden" ) || $el.is( ":disabled" ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    var tabIndex = +$el.attr( "tabindex" );
    tabIndex = isNaN( tabIndex ) ? -1 : tabIndex;
    return $el.is( ":input, a[href], area[href], iframe" ) || tabIndex > -1;
}
```

Comment: I know the list of the items which can receive focus. However, I want some ready and tested solution which covers all cases which I might not be aware about.

Comment: Check if updated answer helps you.

Comment: jQuery has this built in, simply use `$el.is(':focusable')` http://api.jqueryui.com/focusable-selector/

Comment: This is from jQuery UI, _not_ jQuery core. So why the downvote, could you explain me?

Comment: Elements with a height of 0 are not focusable

Comment: anchors in Firefox on MacOS is not always focusable by default. I mean you can put focus on them programmatically, but not with tabbing

Comment: This answer is outdated