# How to test whether an input form field is focussed?

Tags: javascript, testing, focus, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

For the following sign-up form I configured that the first input field with `id="signUpName"` is focused when the form is rendered. [Backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) is used to create the form.

[image: Sign-in form]

I want to test with [Jasmine v.1.3.0](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/tree/v1.3.0) whether a certain input form field is focussed when I load a view:

```
it("should focus the name field of the sign-up form", function() {
  var signUpName = userController.loginView.signUpForm.$el.find("#signUpName");
  userController.loginView.showSignUpForm();
  expect(signUpName).toBeFocused();
  // expect(signUpName.is(":focus")).toBe(true);
});
```

Jasmine prompts:

```
Expected '<input id="signUpName" name="signUpName" type="text">' to be focused.
```

As you can see from the spec I use the [`toBeFocused()`](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#jquery-matchers) matcher from [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery). I run the latest version 1.5.93 of the extension. I also found the discussion on the implementation of `toBeFocused()` and noticed that they meanwhile changed it to the [alternative implementation](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/pull/37#commitcomment-1164439) suggested by Ryan Greenberg.

As an alternative I tried to spy on the *focus* event - if there actually is one?

```
it("should focus the name field of the sign-up form", function() {
  var signUpName = userController.loginView.signUpForm.$el.find("#signUpName");
  var spyEvent = spyOnEvent(signUpName, 'focus');
  userController.loginView.showSignUpForm();;
  expect('focus').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(signUpName);
  expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
});
```

Jasmine prompts:

```
Expected event focus to have been triggered on [object Object]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: @SachynKosare I already read this thread as you could guess from the uncommented line in my spec. Still I have no clue why the test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar problem on MindMup, where the issue was that focus wasn't triggered on that particular object, but on a different jQuery selector that matched that object. We wrote a few matchers for Jasmine that check if the event was actually triggered on a equivalent jQuery set of DOM elements. See https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs/blob/master/test-lib/jquery-extension-matchers.js

With that, you can do:

```
spyOn(jQuery.fn, 'focus').and.callThrough();
// your test
expect(jQuery.fn.focus).toHaveBeenCalledOnJQueryObject(yourObject);
```