# Populating input box that has focus with buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to input numbers into a input boxes from buttons. I am having a hard time figuring out how to find which input box has focus. Is there anything to tell me which input box has focus?

Comment: name on server side, or id via client side

Comment: you say javascript... jQuery?

Comment: As you say you are setting the value with button, you must be using Javascript already. Care to share what you have already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var focused =  document.activeElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a new selector:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].focus = function( elem ) {
  return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
};
```

and test it like this:

```
if ($("#idOfTextBox").is(":focus")) {
  ...
}
```

See [Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're trying to do:

It creates a button next to a text field, then you clic on the button and it sets focus to the text field

```
<form name="myform2">
<input type="text" name="mytextfield2">
<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Set Focus" OnClick="document.myform2.mytextfield2.focus();">
</form>
```

Or with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.forms['myform'].elements['mytextfield'].focus();
</script>
```