# Tell if <input> or <textarea> has focus using native Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you tell if an input or textarea has focus in native javascript?

**This is not a duplicate as it asks for a native Javascript solution!**

Comment: You said you need a native JS solution, so the `jQuery` tag should have not been added, I've just removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Javascript (>= IE 8)

```
!~[].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea"), document.activeElement)
```

Comment: if you know the answer then why ask ?

Comment: Good question @Riturajratan! I was trying to find a question that answered this although I was not able to. I then came up with a solution of my own and decided to turn it into a question for other people could benefit and enjoy it.

Comment: so i think first you search then ask question any way cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

use **[:focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)**

```
$("input, textarea").is(":focus")
```

see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)** it will helpful