# JQuery activeElement on multidimensional input names

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have form input fields like the code below, can I figure what "index" is in focus?

```
<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]"> // index 0
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]"> // index 0

<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]"> // index 1
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]"> // index 1

<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]"> // index 2
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]"> // index 2
```

If the first item is filled and the user selects another item input, how could I figure which "index" is selected?

Comment: What you want to do man ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: I have an Ajax list that pops down from the input with matches to the typed content as the user types in the input box.  Once a selection is clicked from the list, the ajax list loads pulled data into specified input values.  Since I am working with multidimensional input names, I need to specify which input fields to populate.  On my form, there are 4 other fields on the same "index" that need to be populated from the ajax loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to  *search for a given element from among the matched elements*

Try this:

```js
$('[name="myField[\'item_name\'][]"]').on('focus', function() {
  alert($('[name="myField[\'item_name\'][]"]').index(this))
});

$('[name="myField[\'item_qty\'][]"]').on('focus', function() {
  alert($('[name="myField[\'item_qty\'][]"]').index(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]">// index 0
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]">// index 0

<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]">// index 1
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]">// index 1

<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]">// index 2
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]">// index 2
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/somjcz0s/)

**To bind events on dynamically added elements, Use [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

Try this:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '[name="myField[\'item_name\'][]"]', function() {
  alert($('[name="myField[\'item_name\'][]"]').index(this))
});

$(document).on('focus', '[name="myField[\'item_qty\'][]"]', function() {
  alert($('[name="myField[\'item_qty\'][]"]').index(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]">// index 0
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]">// index 0

<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]">// index 1
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]">// index 1

<input type="text" name="myField['item_name'][]">// index 2
<input type="text" name="myField['item_qty'][]">// index 2
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/somjcz0s/1/)

Comment: This mostly worked except for dynamically added content.  I ended up using the same code just in an onFocus= function called from the form's input HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using index on foucs

```
$("input[type='text'][name^='myField']").focus(function(){
  console.log($(this).index())
})
```