# Getting focussed element immediately after focusout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 text inputs which are related to each other and I need to validate once user tabs out of both the input text fields. This is a snapshot:

[image]

And the HTML counterpart:

```
<div class="four float_left field_div_wrapper">
    <div class="padding_5">
        <div class="field_title">
            Telephon rumah
        </div>
        <div class="twelve height_30 land_phone_div">
            <input type="text" id="telephon_rumah_field_1" class="three land_phone_field_1 land_phone_field">
            <input type="text" id="telephon_rumah_field_2" class="eight land_phone_field_2 land_phone_field">
        </div>
        <div class="twelve float_left clear_left red_text display_hidden error_div_text">
            This field must be numeric with 3 to 4 and 7 to 8 digits
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code for validating the 2 text fields of land phone:

```
function performLandPhoneValidationOnDiv(landphoneDiv) {
    var landPhoneValid = true;
    // Here we consider both fields (code of area and office / home phone numbers) for validation if they are non-empty
    // If both the fields are empty then it is a valid entry!
    var areaCodeField = $(landphoneDiv).find(".land_phone_field_1");
    var phoneField = $(landphoneDiv).find(".land_phone_field_2");

    // We need to check current focus and perform validations only if both the text fields do not have focus currently
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2684561/260665
//    var phoneFieldsHasFocus = $(areaCodeField).is(":focus") || $(phoneField).is(":focus");
    var phoneFieldsHasFocus = $(landphoneDiv).is(":focus");

    if (!phoneFieldsHasFocus) {
.
.
.
// Internal validation to check if both the fields (area & phone) has valid data
    }

    return landPhoneValid;
}
```

And the code which triggers this validation is blur: (I have also tried focusout)

```
$(".land_phone_field").blur(function () {
    performLandPhoneValidationOnDiv($(this).closest(".land_phone_div"));
});
```

**Problem**: As you can see in the first image, as soon as I tab out from first field, validation is triggered even before user attempts to enter something in the second section of the phone field.

To avoid this I have tried the following in the performLandPhoneValidationOnDiv callback after the event is triggered:

```
var phoneFieldsHasFocus = $(areaCodeField).is(":focus") || $(phoneField).is(":focus");
```

And:

```
var phoneFieldsHasFocus = $(landphoneDiv).is(":focus");
```

Both return false as result. I suspect this is so because the blur / focusout event is triggered as soon as I tab out and even before any other element gains focus. For the same reason I tried to see if the parent  contains focus in the interim by any chance, it seems not to be the case.

I can handle this situation by using booleans and set the state when user tabs out of both the fields to perform validation, but it would not be a clean solution and I want to know the best way to handle such situations.

Comment: Attach `focus` event for `:input` elements instead.. `this` inside handler will return `element` in focus!

Comment: How would this solve my problem? How would I know that field 2 is expecting focus when user has tabbed out of field 1?