# jQuery ignoring second condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written a jQuery function which I intended to check when shift key is pressed specifically when a certain element has focus.

Below is the code I have written

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 9 && e.shiftKey) {
        if ($(".focus > a").focus) {
            alert("test");
        }
    }
});
```

However, the alert seems to function when shift key is pressed regardless of whether or not `.focus >` a has focus. Have I made an error here or is this a bug?

Comment: `focus` is a method, and, for that matter, it's not used to check if an element is focused, but to bind an event when that element is focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($(".focus > a").focus` will check if there is an attribute defined as `focus` at `$(".focus > a")` object. Due to it exists, your condition is always true.

so change to:

```
if $(".focus > a").is(":focus") .....
```

[Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions that are duplicates. And since you linked to that question, you know it is a duplicate.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no i thought that the real point in THIS question is the way the `if` condition was designed, while the linked question directly asks for a way to check if it's focused. - this is why i've not marked dupe

Comment: Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/150032), especially the "When are two questions considered duplicates?" section. To me, this falls into the second paragraph of that section.

Comment: `This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.` - my idea was that there may be another if check like `if $( ".myClass).attr` or something else - in this case my short explanation at the top of my answer would also hit the point...i don't know whos opinion does fit better here...what do you think?

Comment: I think that since no-one else in the community bothered to mark this as a duplicate, we're probably good as it is. Have a nice day :)