# how to prevent blur() running when clicking a link in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i have:

```
<input type="text" />
```

and

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    alert('stay focused!');
});
```

I want to prevent the blur function running when I'm "blurring" by clicking on an anchor element.

I.E. if i tab to another input, click somewhere on the page etc i want the blur to fire, but if i click a link, I don't want it to fire.

Is this easily achievable, or do i need to hack about with delegates and semaphores?

Thanks

Comment: The `blur()` will fire *before* JavaScript knows where the `focus()` is going. So it's not easily do-able.

Comment: You can try something like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516152/how-to-select-an-element-that-has-focus-on-it-with-jquery/516172#516172 and then assign a click handler to the `<a>` elements which sets the focus to the $('#' + id) element

Comment: thats what i thought, was wondering if there was some magicks i was unaware of

Comment: @David i suppose i could store what element was blurred, then fire the blur event on anything else focused that wasnt an anchor....

Comment: Yeah, I'd imagine that [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) might be your friend with this...

Comment: You may try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/y8X8X/), but it feels hackish.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had to solve this problem myself today, too. I found that the mousedown event fires *before* the blur event, so all you need to do is set a variable that indicates that a mousedown event occurred first, and then manage your blur event appropriately if so.

```
var mousedownHappened = false;

$('input').blur(function() {
    if(mousedownHappened) // cancel the blur event
    {
        alert('stay focused!');
        $('input').focus();
        mousedownHappened = false;
    }
    else   // blur event is okay
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
});

$('a').mousedown(function() {
    mousedownHappened = true;
});
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: is this "mousedown before blur" behaviour reliable cross browser? if so, cool!

Comment: I ended up using your solution as well.  It isn't the prettiest solution, but it does work.  Plus you don't have to muck about with setTimeout with this solution.

Comment: Good solution, also working on iphone mobile safari to prevent hiding of the keyboard.

Comment: good solution, although it didn't work for me out of the box (tested in Chrome): namely, $('input').focus() wouldn't set focus on the input. My solution was to wrap it in setTimeout (without time value) like that:

setTimeout(function(){ $('input').focus(); });

Comment: @AlirezaFallah No, sadly that person shamelessly copied and pasted my answer. If you notice his answer was posted on Dec 5 2012, and my answer was posted on Feb 5 2012.

Comment: You may be better off canceling the mousedown event rather than setting a boolean that is used during the propagation of the event to the blur method.  Cancel it with `e.preventDefault()` where `e` is the first parameter to the event handler function.

Comment: @PrestonS: **That's exactly how it should be done.** Suppress *mousedown* event on external element to prevent *blur* event on input. And the best thing is that **suppressing *mousedown* event doesn't prevent *click* event from firing.** Perfect!

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank god for the underrated 'mousedown' event! 'click' always grabs the limelight, normally.

Comment: I am using it with 'e.preventDefault()'. Slightly cleaner solution, but the 'mousedown' find is the real show stopper...

Answer (score 23):

If you want to keep the cursor at its position in a `contenteditable` element, simply:

```
$('button').mousedown(function(){return false;});
```

Comment: If you'd write proper code you'd likely outvote accepted answer. The proper way to do this is `$("button").mousedown(function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); });` which will prevent *blur* event from triggering.

Answer (score 7):

Delay the blur a bit.  If the viewer clicks a link to another page, the page should change before this code gets a chance to run:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {alert('stay focused!');}, 1000);
});
```

You can experiment with what delay value for the timeout seems appropriate.

Comment: i dont want to have to wait for the blur to run when its a "legitimate" blur situation. Yes this works, but its not very elegant :(

Comment: Blur gets called before anything else and there doesn't appear to be any way to know what is coming next after the blur event (e.g. whether it's a click on a link or not).  So, the ONLY way to defer processing of the blur event until you know what comes next is with a delay.  You can experiment with how much of a delay is required to make it work.  I found that 100ms was not enough in Chrome, but 1000ms was enough.  This is the kind of area where browsers tend to differ so you'd have to do a lot of cross browser testing.

Comment: If you describe the whole problem you're trying to solve, there may be a better way to solve it that doesn't need this delay.

Comment: Most things that involve timings are bad, in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

You can get this behavior by calling `preventDefault()` in the `mousedown` event of the control being clicked (that would otherwise take focus). For example:

```
btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})

btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    input.value += '@'
    input.setSelectionRange(ta.value.length, ta.value.length)
})
```

See [live example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wm2IBe?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Some clarification that was too long to put in a comment.

The `click` event represents both pressing the mouse button down, AND releasing it on a particular element.

The `blur` event fires when an element loses focus, and an element can lose focus when the user "clicks" off of the element. But notice the behavior. An element gets blurred as soon as you press your mouse DOWN. You don't have to release.

That is the reason why `blur` gets fired before `click`.

A solution, depending on your circumstances, is to call `preventDefault` on `mousedown` and `touchstart` events. These events always (I can't find concrete documentation on this, but articles/SO posts/testing seem to confirm this) fire before `blur`.

This is the basis of Jens Jensen's answer.