# How do I properly capture the right click event on a div with contentEditable=true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, focus, markdown

I have a div with `contentEditable=true`. It supports markdown formatting for `**word**` and `_word_`.

On the `blur` event on the `div`, markdown is converted to html.
On the `focus` event on the `div`, html is converted to markdown.

This is ok. But when the browser finds an unknown word (red underline) and I want to fix it with a right click to see the suggested words, the `div` takes the focus and the word is not underlined.

Have you an idea please? (sorry for my English language)

Comment: @jwnace Did my answer solve your problem

Comment: @elzi, It's not my question, I just edited it. Sven, did elzi's answer solve your problem?

Comment: @elzi : Thanks, but my problem is not solve with your answer. I would like the browser context menu appears before the change of state in focus, for choose a word suggested by the browser's dictionary in the context menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621711/how-to-prevent-blur-running-when-clicking-a-link-in-jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `oncontextmenu` - since the right click could also be achieved by CTRL/CMD+click, etc.

```
$('#content').on('contextmenu', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log('context menu opened');
})
```

**EDIT** Adjusting based on your comment feedback:

```
$('#content').on('mousedown', function (event) {

    if ( event.which == 3 ) {
      console.log('Right mouse button pressed');
    }
})
```

Comment: I do not have a context menu with this solution.

Comment: The second solution? I get a context menu fine: http://jsbin.com/kewucujafa/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: ok, sorry. But left click is now inactive and my div can not take the focus.

Comment: Just remove `event.preventDefault()`. New JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/gimatidati/2/edit

Comment: Works great for me. What's the problem?

Comment: By steps : 1-add space at the end of sentence / 2-"worrd" is underlined / 3-click other place for blur / 4-right-click on "worrd" for show suggested words. On step 4, the contextual menu appears, but no suggestions because sentence is different, with html to markdown

Comment: Now we're getting into a second phase of the problem. I was only intending to show you how to get into the right click event. Give me some time.