# How to select the element that has the focus?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select an element that has focus on it with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516152/how-to-select-an-element-that-has-focus-on-it-with-jquery)

I have several HTML elements on the page. I want to write a JQuery code the tells me which element has the focus. I doesn't whether the element gets the focus because I clicked it or I used the tab key. The most important think is that it tells me which element has the focus

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

Thank for helping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/516152/235710

Comment: @MohammadAdil, that's almost what I was looking for. But I don't know how to give you credit.

Comment: No need for credit... i just glad it helped you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var focusedElement = $(':focus');
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.activeElement` should return the current element that is in focus.

> Returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any. This attribute is read only.

**Ref:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement