# How to determine if a field has focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very similar to [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus) except that I'm not trying find the field that has focus, I just need to know if a particular one already has focus. Is that possible?

Comment: Um, can't you use the solutions in that question to find the focused element and compare it against the element of your chosing?

Comment: @ide: yes. was just leaving work, didn't have time to read through all the solutions.

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
$("input#id").is(":focus")
```

**Edit**:
You should read this post if you plan to use it on older browsers.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-the-focus-selector-valid

Comment: Try is correct since it doesn't work everywhere I believe, so this is best answer, or $("*:focus")

Answer (score 3):

You can do this rather simply with jQuery: `$(el).is(":focus")`