# Javascript- document/window has focus?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which Javascript element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus)

Is it possible to check in Javascript whether the current window has focus?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not really. May be you could assign handlers to the focus/blur events of the window, setting a boolean to true or false and use that to determine if it has focus or not.

Something along this line:

```
window.hasfocus = false;

window.onfocus = function(){
   this.hasfocus = true;
}

window.onblur = function(){
   this.hasfocus = false;
}
```

Comment: Great idea, however I would set the standard value to `true`, because when you load the code the window probably already has the focus.