# Lock tab key with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to lock or disable and again the tab key with javascript?

Comment: In what purpose you need to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *lock/disable a tab key*? Do you mean how to prevent **TAB** key from transfering focus to next focusable element?

Comment: Answers below are good, but let me warn you, most users won't like you to prevent them for using their tab. In my case, if it isn't for a game, I'd leave the website ASAP.

Comment: Google docs is a good non-game example of disabling tab.  Tab actually works like a tab, doesn't transfer focus.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov One good use case is if you're doing something like a Block UI, i.e. to stop the user from doing anything until an operation is finished or to create a modal dialog.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
        objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
})
```

Comment: that's work so And open again? and  can I use any selector in place of $(document)

Comment: @psygnosis, short answer: *yes* :-)

Comment: Last question iPhone safari browser has next and previous button.. like works tab key.. But this codes doesnt work on iphone next button.. How can I do that?

Comment: How to revert it back?

Comment: Revert what back @prgmrDev ?

Comment: @Neal How to revert the preventDefault() on tab keypress?  I tried returning false but its not working. Somehow we need to unbind preventDefault(). But I don't know how to do that

Comment: This works when I press the tab key after certain intervals, however pressing the tab key twice in a short interval doesn't

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
$(":input, a").attr("tabindex", "-1");
```

That will disable getting focus with tab in all links and form elements.

Hope this helps

Comment: @psygnosis $(":input, a").removeAttr("tabindex");

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Naftali aka Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871645/1599699), here's how you'd do it with vanilla JS and both start and stop Tab behavior buttons:

```js
let stopTabFunction = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
document.getElementById('stopTabButton').onclick = function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', stopTabFunction);
};
document.getElementById('resumeTabButton').onclick = function() {
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', stopTabFunction);
};
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="stopTabButton" value="Stop Tab!"/>
<input type="button" id="resumeTabButton" value="Resume Tab!"/>
```

Note that this also works for Shift + Tab (reverse direction).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om0q8u6y)

---

However, in my case, I wanted slightly different behavior: I wanted to basically lock down Tab focus to a single `div`. To do this, I placed a `div` before and after it, gave them both [`tabindex="0"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) (document-defined tab order on the `div`'s themselves), to make the outer edges of the `div` focusable, like so:

```html
<div id="beforeMyDiv"></div>
<div id="myDiv">
  <!-- Only want Tab indexing to occur in here! -->
</div>
<div id="afterMyDiv"></div>
```

Then, I changed the function from earlier to this:

```js
//Get the div's into variables etc.
//...

let forceTabFocusFunction = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        //Force focus onto the div.
        if (!myDiv.contains(document.activeElement)) {
            if (e.shiftKey) {
                afterMyDiv.focus();
            } else {
                beforeMyDiv.focus();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

That did the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

On Neal answer, I'd only add:

```
if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
    return;
}
```

Because when you finish typing CPF and press TAB, it counts as a character and changes to CNPJ mask.

Complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cpfcnpj").keydown(function(objEvent){
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
            return;
        }
        try {
            $("#cpfcnpj").unmask();
        } catch (e) {}

        var size= $("#cpfcnpj").val().length;

        if(size < 11){
            $("#cpfcnpj").mask("999.999.999-99");
        } else {
            $("#cpfcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
        }                   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English.Stack Overflow is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.

Comment: Translated to english.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Lol