# How to keep focus on text field at all times (MVC 4 c#)

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, textfield

I have a text field that always needs to be focused no matter what the user does.

I have activated the text field on load by doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
    < script type ="text/javascript" src ="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></ script>
    < script type ="text/javascript">
    $( function () {
        $( "#myTextBox2" ).focus();
    });
    </ script>
</head>
< body>
    < div>
        < input type ="text" id ="myTextBox">
        < input type ="text" id ="myTextBox2"onblur="var that= this; setTimeout(function() { that.focus(); }, 0);">
    </ div>
</ body>
</html>
```

If I press the tab button when trying the code above I can still tab away from myTextBox2, but I cant click on myTextBox with my mouse (which is right).

If the user presses any button or clicks anywhere on the site the text field should still be selected and focused. How do I enforce this completely?

Edit:
Adding this to the header in my code and to the answer by Sven seems to do the trick:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
            objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
       }
    })
```

Credit:
[Lock tab key with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871626/lock-tab-key-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the focus on the text field at all time with the following code:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="focus" />
    <input type="text" name="name2" />
    <input type="text" name="name3" />
    <input type="text" name="name4" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#focus").focus().bind('blur', function() {
        $(this).focus();            
    }); 

    $("html").click(function() {
        $("#focus").val($("#focus").val()).focus();
    });  

    //disable the tab key
    $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
            objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
       }
    })      
});​
```

Example on JsFiddle: [Click!](http://jsfiddle.net/QcSPB/10/)

I had to replace the value of the textfield to force/trigger the placement of the cursor in the focused field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice and quick. But one more thing that whenever I try to focus to another textbox with mouse click, the textbox regains the focus but the text in that is selected. It should not select the text and the pointer should point to the end of text. BTW I haven't asked this question.

Comment: And also, if you change focus to be the last (fourth) text field you can tab away from it. I.e it seems to work as long as there is another text after it.

Comment: @KULKING thx, I updated the answer. Removed the `select()` and resetted the textbox value to force the cursor in the textfield and at the end of the text.

Comment: @mdc updated my answer, now the tabindex on other elements (only inputs in example) are disabled so the tab key won't do anything anymore.

Comment: @Sven Hm...I can still tab away from the last text field? (Tried it in ie10 and chrome). Actually my original code has the same error. Change places with myTextBox and myTextBox2 and it works.

Comment: @mdc what do you mean? I use chrome and I can't tab to the other text fields in the JsFiddle example.

Comment: @Sven If you move id="focus" to "name4" instead of "name" you cant tab away? ...I can?

Comment: @mdc ahh i see, strange. When you set the id to the last element then the tab button defocus the field. I think you can catch the key event of the tab button and prevent the default action for it as an work-around.

Comment: @Sven Yes check out my edit in the OP. Add that to your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @mdc added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would to the following:

1) On page load, make the element focused automatically ( already done by you )

2) On #myTextBox2 create a key press event handler and discard every char except of the "real" input ones e.g. alfanumeric, dots, carets, and everything the user can actually input on that field

3) Create an onblur event handler on #myTextBox2 that actually focuses on the same input ( already done by you, I would suggest to put it on a script in the  )

4) For completeness, put an Interval on your page that checks every X microseconds that the input is focused. If not, make the input focused. This is optional.

Be aware that, in any case, if a function call actually detects that the input is not focused, and has to focus it, the focus will be pointed at the beginning of the input, so the user input will re-begin from the beginning of the input field. The input contents will not be destroyed, however the user will have to jump to the end of the input after the re-focus.

If you need any help in creating the event handlers, just ask.