# Globally Disable Tab Key on Page

Tags: java, javascript, smartgwt

How can I globally disable the use of the tab key on page? I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871626/lock-tab-key-with-javascript), but it uses jQuery and I am not using jQuery. I know I can set tabIndex equal to -1 to disable keyboard focus, but this is for a GWT web application that uses GWT-Ext, mixed with SmartGWT, and OpenLayers so it would be easier to just set it once in the page for the entire set of controls (and there are over a hundred different controls).

Comment: Why would you do this? Users who don't (or are physically unable to) use a mouse won't be able to use your page if they can't tab between controls...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Because I have a need to do it

Comment: @0A0D Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to add this in my `EntryPoint` class using SmartGWT:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler()
{
   @Override
   public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event)
   {
      // tab is key 9
      if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == 9)
      {
         event.cancel();
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
window.onkeydown = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I checked this by entering it in the console of Google Chrome and it disables the Tab key.

Comment: It's not working for me, but it could be something with GWT... I am trying to figure it out

Comment: Can you show some live page, that is similar to what you have or do you have a fiddle to share? Coz this is working for me and I have given how to test it too!!! It works even in this StackOverflow page!!!

Comment: I wish I could.. it's local to our system. I have it working on StackOverflow too.