# How to not go to next form field on TAB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Trying to search online and can only find how to change field selection..

My question today is the opposite

Is it possible to not go to the next field on tab button press, if yes how can we do that.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock tab key with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871626/lock-tab-key-with-javascript)

Comment: Please dont post duplicate Questions !!Its dangerous for Users and stackoverflow!

Comment: I am very sorry if you guys feel like I did took the time to waste my time, I did make my research And I did not find my awnser ( kinda normal with the title of the previous question )   Also @VickyGonsalves If you think that is funny that I included the question in the body of my op, think about the following. On stack overflow (like every forum) has some poeple that will bash people if they dont make the minimum in my op there is not mutch to say. I then try to be the more specific posible so people like you wont make fun off me. Clearly It didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#blockThisFieldID').keydown(function(objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
        objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#testform").on('keydown', 'input', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } 
});


<div id="testform">
    <input type=text id=test1><br />
    <input type=text id=test2><br />
    <input type=text id=test3><br />
</div>
```

[As seen in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m86hK/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the **tabIndex**?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: He wants to disable it, not change the order