# tab key press ignore hidden area a & button elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, tabindex

**[JsBin Link](https://output.jsbin.com/suqiqucogu)**

In this above link I have added some `<div>` with `<a>` and `<button>` elements. I have a right side bar div with some `<a>` tags and I have a footer in bottom side. It contains few `<button>` elements.

Problem is When I press the **tab** key via keyboard it focuses on footer div `<button>` element. But, footer div should be shown when jQuery function is called. It should not shown when tab key is pressed. The same problem is occuring in right side bar div also. Right side bar div contains `<a>` tag. It should be shown when I click the text *"Open Right Side Div"*. But, it is also showing when I press the **tab** key.

I found two solution for this issue.

1. If I add `display: none` in footer and right side bar classes instead of `bottom: -40px` and `transform: translateX(100%)`.
2. `tabindex="-1"` will solve focusing problems

I know these above two solutions to ignore focusing hidden div elements. But, I can't use these two solutions. In my case I have **n number of hidden divs** (hidden div contains n number of `<a>` & `<button>`) in my application.

Is there any other way to programmatically ignore focusing `<a>` & `<button>` from **hidden divs** (not normal divs) when I press the tab key?

Comment: To hide element you need `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. If you move it outside of the page, the page will scroll to show the element.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'disabled' attribute?

Comment: @J03L `disabled` will not help. I have tried this too..

Comment: @jcubic I don't want to hide the element. I want to **ignore focussing** on hidden div elements when I press the tab key.

Comment: You can block "Tab" Key by javascript.
[See this artical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871626/lock-tab-key-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button tabindex="2" >Tab focus 2</button>
<button tabindex="1" >Tab Should not focus</button>
<button tabindex="3" >Tab focus 3</button>
<button tabindex="4" >Tab focus 4</button>
<button tabindex="5" >Tab focus 5</button>
```

You can just manipulate tabindex attribute to skip the focus , basically you start with bigger number and carry on, and give smaller no the the elements that you want to hide form tab focus

p.s: in the page, all elements that has ability to focus use tabindex attribute

Comment: If I want to skip the focus, simple I can use `tabindex=-1`. When I press the tab key, If divs are hidden `(I mean out of focus div elements)` and it contains few `<a>` and `<button>` elements that shouldn't be focussed..

Answer (score 0):

In your example, nothing is hidden. Every single div is visible and therefor the tab behavior ist perfectly correct.

As statet in the comments You should initialize your footer div hidden with css style="display:none;".

To make it visible after a change event or button click via jQuery You can do something like this:

```
$('div.footer').css('display','block');
```