# how to disable default function of tab key in primefaces

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

i am new in PF and JSF. Could you tell me how can i prevent default function of tab key. It's default function is to go next input area but i dont want it. I wwant to put new function behind it. I try codebelow and it doesnt work. actualy i tried it with enter key(event.keyCode==13) and it worked.

```
<p:column>
                                <p:remoteCommand name="test"
                                                 actionListener="#{otomatikHesapAcilisController.getSecimSonucu}"/>
                                <p:inputNumber id="inputSecim"
                                               decimalPlaces="0"
                                               value="#{otomatikHesapAcilisController.secim}"
                                               onkeypress="if ( event.keyCode == 9) { test(); }"/>
                            </p:column>
```

Comment: May I ask why you would need such a construction? Why would you not allow to tab? Bad for usability and accessibility.

Comment: yes sure. actually i think same with you but the people we work with asked us this. They dont want to pass next input when pressed the tab, they want a spesific function.

Comment: I would assign it to a different key

Comment: i would too but this is the situation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock tab key with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871626/lock-tab-key-with-javascript)

Comment: no, this is not an answer.