# Determine HTML Node name given a javascript selection object

Tags: javascript, dom, selection

How can I determine the node (what tag this innerHTML is associated with) that is associated with a given javascript selection object?  I am using window.getSelection() and would like to know in which div/span class the selection is in.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which Javascript element has focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the deepest element that contains the whole of the selection, the easiest way is to obtain a `Range` object from the selection and use its `commonAncestorContainer` property.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5LvEG/1/

Code:

```
function getSelectionContainerElementId() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var container = range.commonAncestorContainer;

        // container could be a text node, so use its parent if so
        if (container.nodeType == 3) {
            container = container.parentNode;
        }
        return container.id;
    }
    return null;
}

alert(getSelectionContainerElementId());
```