# Bookmark to write something in Browser Textbox

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarks

I wanted to know if it is possible to make a Bookmark in my Browser (Chrome/FF).

which on clicking, Write something like `stack overflow` or anything in the currently active textbox in browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus

Comment: check out http://pm5544.github.com/formStore/ it might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
javascript:var x = function() {if (document.activeElement) document.activeElement.value='stack overflow';};void(x());
```

or just

```
javascript:void(if (document.activeElement) document.activeElement.value='stack overflow');
```

Comment: Man..just one thing...
You are AWESOME \m/\m/ :D :D
Thank u so so so Much :D

Comment: done.. :)
nd just one more thing..it works fine on every site..but not on omegle.com..why so?