# Javascript code to detect if focus is in a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, safari-extension

I'm trying to make a safari extension that does something if the cursor focus isn't in a text field. However the following code to detect if the focus isn't in a text field does not work.

```
    if ($(document.activeElement).attr("type") != "text" 
       && $(document.activeElement).attr("type") != "textarea") {
          ..do something
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus

Comment: `textarea` isn't a `type` attribute value - it is a tag name. You probably meant to check `document.activeElement.localName == "textarea"` (yes, sometimes things are simpler without jQuery).

Comment: `localName` isn't implemented in IE 8 or lower. Better (compatible with more browsers) to use `tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just keep it simple:

```
var el = document.activeElement;

if (el && (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' && el.type == 'text' ||
    el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea')) {
  // focused element is a text input or textarea
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to achive this

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
   alert('Focused');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("input[type=text]").filter(":not(:focus)").css("background","#ff0000");

$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background","#ffffff");
});

$("input[type=text]").blur(function(){
    $(this).css("background","#ff0000");
});
```

Should set all the non-active inputs' background to red. (Worked in Chrome 18)