# How to deactivate keypress event at textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I was writing an javascript application. I used something like

```
document.keypress = function(e) {
    switch(e.which){ 
    case 97: 
    alert('foobar');
    break;
    .......
```

And it works fine! Now, somewhere in the html page i have a textarea, Now, whenever i type `a` (i.e, ASCII 97) then it `alert`'s (obviously).

The question is how do i prevent this? with my keypress event working for everything except inside textareas, and text fields?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - you want the alert to only show when you type "a" inside a textbox?

Comment: no, he wants to show alert only when not typing into textarea, textfields...

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()` with in the `keypress` event of your textarea or textfield

Comment: @RaoulGeorge : I want the alert to only show when i type "a" anywhere in the window, but when the textarea is focused, i don't want to show it!

Comment: @zzlalani : I am sorry that didn't help

Comment: @zzlalani : I am sorry that didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `target` attribute to identify the element that triggered the event.
Then, use `tagName` to figure out the element type.

You can use other properties like `type` to figure out if it is a text field.

```
document.keypress = function(e) {
var target = e.target;
var elementType = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
if (elementType != "textarea" && !(elementType =="input" && target.type =="text")) {
    switch(e.which){ 
    case 97: 
    alert('foobar');
    break;
    .......
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify element/elements to which you'll add event listeners, for example:

```
document.getElementById('text-field').keypress = function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    switch (code) {
        case 97:
            alert('foobar');
            break;
        ....
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is jQuery's [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method.

From the docs -

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$(':input').on('keypress', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jdpsv/6/)

When you click inside the textbox, the alert will not be shown. When you click anywhere else in the document, the alert will be displayed.

Comment: It says he's using a textarea. heheh. `input` ? heheh

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible approaches:

1. Add onfocus/onblur handlers to your text inputs, to clear/set document.keypress.
2. Within the handler, get the currently focused element

[How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)

And then use the .tagName and .type properties to determine whether it's a text input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `keyPress` method.

#### http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

here's how to use it :

```
$("#target").keypress(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
$(document).on("keypress",function(e){
    switch(e.which){ 
      case 97: 
       alert('foobar');
       break;
    }
});

$('textarea,input[type="text"]').on("keypress",function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7ghb/

I hope it helps.