# Javascript / jQuery to obtain the id of the textarea that I am typing in

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, textarea, jquery-events

I have a simple form with three textareas each with a different id. I want to be able to press the button and return the id of the textarea where I am typing in. Instead when I press the button I receive the id of the button which is button1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    function printTagName() {
      $("#p1").html($(":focus").attr("id"));
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea3"></textarea>
  </form>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="printTagName()">Press</button>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Use document.activeElement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is clicked focus shifts to the button.  Save the element when a `textarea` receives focus, then print out the `id` of the `textarea`.

```
var focusElement = {};

$("textarea").focus(function(){
   focusElement = this;
});

$("#button1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#p1").html(focusElement.id);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZYK7f/

Comment: Why not use $(this) if you use .attr or use focusElement.id instead of casting it again to a jQuery object?

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you very much for your solution. It worked when I put your javascript code inside a
$(document).ready(function() {
...
});
Thanks again and all the best.

Comment: Then I should not have edited my post which now again stores the ID and not the object.

Answer (score 1):

This would work unless you need to know if whatever had focus no longer has it.

For example if the user clicks something that is NOT a textarea before hitting the button and you need to know this, the code will become quite complex

```
var hadFocus;
$(function() {
  $("textarea").on("focus",function() { hadFocus=this.id; });
});
function printTagName() {
  $("#p1").html(hadFocus || "No textarea had focus");
}
```

Comment: Downvoters who do not comment should be banned!

Answer (score 0):

Save the TextArea that has focus last using:

```
var lastFocus;
$("TextArea").focus(function () {
   lastFocus = this;
});
```

And this call the printTagName function

```
function printTagName() {
   $("p").html(lastFocus.id);
});
```

Comment: if you use attr you need to use $(this) if not, use lastFocus.id. In any case already answered twice

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Kevin Bowersox and everyone else for answering my question. Here is the complete code for Kevin's solution (I added a $(document).ready(function() {...}); to his solution):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var focusElement = {};

      $("textarea").focus(function(){
        focusElement = this;
      });

      $("#button1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#p1").html($(focusElement).attr("id"));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea3"></textarea>
  </form>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <button type="button" id="button1">Press</button>
</body>
</html>
```