# Finding the form element that has focus

Tags: javascript, dom, focus

I would like to know, via javascript, which give a form element has the `focus()`, to be able to switch to a variable that holds the name of the currently active.

But without using frameworks like `jQuery`.

And without the use `onfocus event` within each component of the form.

Is that possible?

M.

Answer (score 1):

You could get it by:

```
document.activeElement
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
  document.formname.activeElement
```

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus).