# GWT input text focus is automatic disabled

Tags: java, gwt, text, input

I have a input text. When I am writing some text into input text suddenly focus is disabled.
Example : I want to write **Playmate**, but when I have written **Pla** my focus is disabled and I cant to continue other letters (exactly : **ymate**), my focus is dissapeared.

Maybe anyone have encountered with my bug ?

1. GWT 2.4.0
2. Browser : Internet Explorer 8

Comment: is there a listener or something similar on that field(async/sync servercall)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the error logs. My guess is that there is a listener (for example for auto completion) and it encounters a problem.

If that's not the case, then some other component might steal the focus. See this question: [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)

I suggest to start a timer in the `focus` event handler (i.e. start a timer when the element gets the focus), wait 4 seconds and then execute `console.log(document.activeElement);`

You can then see in the console which element has the focus. Or maybe restart the timer every 500ms to see how the focus moves.

Comment: Actually I have this problem on all of input text fields. Everywhere I try to write some text in input text I encounter this bug. Also I have to inform that I have done some actions before try to search, if I dont do it I dont have a problem, and I have invistigated that my bug is appeared after 3 sec after I focus on input text.

But why I dont have this bug in Google Chrome ??

Comment: Do you have any addons installed in IE?

Comment: Only GWT Pluggin. I have added javascript behind. And I have seen these actions : GOT FOCUS ... (3 sec) FOCUS IS DISABLED ....(2 sec) ONBLUR.
Every 3 seconds focus is disabled.

Comment: Where do you see the text "FOCUS IS DISABLED"?

Comment: FOCUS IS DISABLED - it's not a message, I just cant write text in input text field. This is workflow (actions) - GOT FOCUS ... (3 sec) FOCUS IS DISABLED ....(2 sec) ONBLUR.

Comment: Okay. FYI: The focus can't be disabled, the correct term is "focus is lost". The odd thing is that the ONBLUR event happens so late. Also check that disabled form fields look different (to make sure that some JavaScript isn't disabling the field while you type but you can't see this).