# How to Check if form is out of focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to check if a form is out of focus, so I could manipulate the DOM accordingly.

I've tried something like this:

```
$("#dialog-form").on("focusout", function () {       
    if ($(document.activeElement).parents('#dialog-form').length === 0) {
        //Do some stuff...
    };
});
```

Because `focusout` binds to all the children elements, this event will fire even when I move the focus between elements in the form. Problem is, length always returns 0 so... obviously this is wrong.

Is there a best practice on the subject?

Edit: (cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<TasksWebApp.Task>
<h2>Tasks Managment Tool</h2>
<hr />
<br />
<ul id="MainUL">
    @{foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <li id="li_@item.Name">
            <div class="taskContainer">
                @if (item.SubTasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    <div class="expand">
                        <button>Expand</button>
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="erase">
                    <button>Erase Task</button>
                </div>
                <div class="addSubClass">
                    <button>Add Sub-Class</button>
                </div>
                <div class="taskDetails">
                    Name: <span>@item.Name</span>&nbsp;
                    Owner: <span>@item.Owner</span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
        
      }
    }
</ul>

<div id="AddMainItem">
    <button>Add Main Item</button>
</div>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create New Task">
    <p class="formHeadPar">All form fields are required:</p>
    <p id="FormComments"></p>
    <form id="AddTaskForm">

        <label for="newTaskName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="newTaskName" id="newTaskName" placeholder="Task Name" />
        <label for="newTaskOwner">Owner:</label>
        <input type="text" name="newTaskOwner" id="newTaskOwner" placeholder="Task Owner" />

        <input type="submit" tabindex="1" value="Add Task" />
        <button id="CloseForm">Close Form</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the selected object with `document.activeElement`, which contains the current element with focus. But be aware that it only can contain elements capable of keystrokes, like input elements and such.

Answer (score 1):

The `focusout` event bubbles, and fires when an element inside the form loses focus, but before a new elements receives the focus, so you have to defer the callback with a timeout to give the `activeElement` property time to update

```
$("#dialog-form *").on("focusout", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ( $(document.activeElement).closest('#dialog-form').length === 0 ) {
            //Do some stuff...
        };
    }.bind(this)); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2jckctu/)