# How to get which element causes blur event for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

One `div` has a bounded `focusout` event. `OnFocusOut`(method name) event some code is getting executed. But i want which element causes `focusout` event. If `e.relatedTarget` is child elements of that `div` then don't execute code from `OnFocusOut` method.

I tried `e.relatedTarget`(working on google chrome), but this variable does not work with firefox(does not support). So i want some alternate solution for e.relatedTarget which supports for all browsers.

**Edit**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaustubhkhare19/sk4fg39q/)

As displays in output,

`Container21` is `contentEditable` div which has focusout event binded.

i want if user clicks on other than `container22` then `doSomthing()`

One restriction is i can not add click event on remaining elements.

Comment: e.target with condition?

Comment: @guradio e.target giving same div on which i binded focusout event, even if i click from outside of the div.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: May be you are looking for `e.stopPropogation()`

Comment: if the target element Container22 can have focus, you could try checking if it has focus in your event. or add a focus-class to it on click and remove that class when the user clicks Container21, then check for that class.

Comment: @KWeiss Each time target value is same i.e. container21, but actual focus is present on another element.

Comment: @KWeiss their are too many containers present in my actual code, so i can not add click event on all containers. I given smallest example in fiddle.

Comment: so you have a lot of different Container21s with different Container22s for each of them?

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus

Comment: @KWeiss no their is only one container21 and container22, but their are other many containers on which if i clicked then, focusout method should doSomthing. 
and if i clicked on container22 then focusout method shouldn't doSomthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Container22 is an element that can have focus, you can check if it has focus in your blur event:

```
$('#container21').blur(function(){
    // timeout because focus does not switch immediately
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (document.activeElement === document.getElementById('container22')) {
            // your logic here: container22 has focus
        } else {
            // your logic here: container22 does not have focus
        }
    }, 60);
});
```

If Container22 cannot have focus, you can give it a class instead:

```
$('#container22').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('fake-focus');
});
```

You remove the class when Container21 gains focus:

```
$('#container21').focus(function(){
    $('#container22').removeClass('fake-focus');
});
```

And you check for the class when Container21 loses focus - if Container22 has the class, that means the user clicked it to focus out. We need a timeout again, because the click event will happen *after* focus is lost.

```
$('#container21').blur(function(){
    // timeout because focus does not switch immediately
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('#container22').hasClass('fake-focus')) {
            // your logic here: container22 was clicked
        } else {
            // your logic here: container22 was not clicked
        }
    }, 60);
});
```