# Inspect element which has tab focus?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Is there a way using Chrome's developer tools to inspect the element which currently has tab focus in the page? I'm trying to identify which element is stealing focus and it's otherwise invisible on the screen.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am not trying to inspect a visible element that disappears when I move the mouse or something. I am trying to locate the element which has actual tab focus in the developer tools "Elements" tab.

Comment: @AlexL Unfortunately I did not find a solution in this other question.

Comment: Indeed. I retracted my flag. Perhaps, [you could use js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus#497108) to find `activeElement`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)