# In js, can you detect when a page has nothing focused?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

On my page, I have multiple text boxes and need at least one of those boxes to always have focus. Is there a js event listener I can call that will detect when nothing on the page has focus, so I can give it focus?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)

Comment: "need at least one of those boxes to always have focus" – That is not possible. Just select the address bar in your browser and any focused element will lose focus.

Comment: I currently have it set up that whenever anywhere on the page is clicked, the text box gets focus. However, there are many buttons that make ajax calls that then cause the page to have nothing focused. Now I could go to every ajax call and set focus to the box after each one, but I'm just wondering if there's something easier, to where I can just let the page recognize that nothing has focus, then in this case set the focus.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if an element from a list of tags is focused :

```
function hasFocus(selector) {
    return Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
        .some(function(el){
            return el === document.activeElement
        });
}

// usage 
console.log(hasFocus('input, select, textarea'))
```

Comment: Instead of `.filter(...).length>0` you could just use `.some(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach a `focusout` handler to the `document` which checks the focusable elements every time a focusout event bubbles up.  Then force focus on an element other than the source of the blur event, if none have it.

Edited per comment.

Comment: blur event will not bubble up by default,change useCapture to true or use another event 'focusout'

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my solution on this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lovelace-f9hei

When you load the page, the first input get focus. Everytime you click out. A random input get focused.

blur event will not bubble up by default. So make it bubble up by changing usecapture to true.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

document.querySelector('input').focus()

document.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  console.log(e)
  if (e.isTrusted) {
    const random = Math.round(Math.random() * (inputs.length-1));
    console.log(random)
    Array.from(inputs)[random].focus()
  }
},true)
```

Comment: Why do you focus on a random element? That doesn't makes too much sense to me...

Comment: The requirement of the question is that "at least one of those boxes to always have focus". I assume it means a random input needs to be focused.