# Can someone explain this condition in a react task?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logical-operators

I have this solution for a react task and there is something I didn't understand.

```
// React is loaded and is available as React and ReactDOM
// imports should NOT be used
class Input extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    let {forwardedRef, ...otherProps} = this.props; 
    return <input {...otherProps} ref={forwardedRef} />;
  }
}

const TextInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <Input {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
});

class FocusableInput extends React.Component {
  
  ref = React.createRef()

  render() {
    return <TextInput ref={this.ref} />;
  }

  // When the focused prop is changed from false to true, 
  // and the input is not focused, it should receive focus.
  // If focused prop is true, the input should receive the focus.
  // Implement your solution below:
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(!prevProps.focused && this.props.focused) this.ref.current.focus();
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.focused && this.ref.current.focus();
  }
}

FocusableInput.defaultProps = {
  focused: false
};

const App = (props) => <FocusableInput focused={props.focused} />;

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In  `componentDidUpdate`  the task is

```
   // When the focused prop is changed from false to true, 
  // and the input is not focused, it should receive focus.
```

So `prevProps.focused` was false and the negation `!prevProps.focused` makes it true.

And `this.props.focused` should be true so that the condition with the logical operator && `(!prevProps.focused && this.props.focused)` can be true.

But the task says it should not be true `// and the input is not focused`

Does that mean  `this.props.focused` should be false?

The condition wouldn't be true with ( true && false) ?

Can someone explain what I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "input is not focused" is not about `focused` prop value, but whether the element is actually focused **in the DOM**. If `this.ref.current` is not focused, then `this.ref.current.focus()` will give keyboard focus to `this.ref.current` but if `this.ref.current` is **already** focused, then `this.ref.current.focus()` will not change anything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You never [check if the element has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus), you only check the props.

This should probably look like this:

```
if(!prevProps.focused && this.props.focused && this.ref.current !== document.activeElement) this.ref.current.focus();
```

But checking for this seems unnecessary since focusing focused element has no performance impact.