# How to access selected multiple td in a table

Tags: javascript, html

[image: calendar]

I am writing a web-app for a calendar, using Javascript. I am trying to give the user the ability to mark multiple days on the calendar in one go (marked like the 1st day of the month in the picture)(my code handled the marking okay, so no worries there).

If I hold down the Ctrl Key while clicking on the table boxes (the < td >) a blue border will appear to make the the boxes appear selected, now this is not marked by my code, it's a result of whatever magics the web browser (FireFox) is doing.

My question is, how do I access the list of these selected boxes (days 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6)? Since the blue border boxes are marked by the web browser, surely there is a way to access them, right? I went through the HTML DOM documents, didn't seems to find any way to access this collection of selected boxes.

I was expecting something like:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").selectedChildren 
or
document.getElementById("myTable").selectedChild[0]
```

but I can't seems to find anything similar. Maybe I'm expecting the wrong thing...

Can anyone kindly point me to the right direction, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I was expecting something like:` expecting or hoping? what makes an element "selected"?

Comment: Those are probably marked because they have [`focus`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus). You might consider adding hidden checkboxes tho if you want to pass the selected items codewise

Comment: @JaromandaX I am expecting there to have something like a list of selected (marked by blue border) < td > elements that the < table > is keeping, if that's where these marks are kept. Apparently it is not kept by the < table > element, so I'd like to know, where or how I can access the list of blue-bordered < td > elements.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have seen solutions like that, but I am a stubborn old C++ programmer ;P, so I'd really like to know if there is a way to access the list of marked/focused elements, maybe something like document.focusedElement or something like that. Well if there isn't a way to do so, maybe I will go with the class method.

Comment: research `window.getSelection()` and work from there

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right! No wander I can't find anything in DOM, that's because it's not in Document level of the model.... Now looking in to Window level  documentations...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this :

```js
var selectedCells = [];

$("#calendar td").on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        // If you click & Ctrl key at the same time
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        // It gives it the class selected or not (so you can select & unselect)
        selectedCells = [];
        $("#calendar td.selected").each(function() {
            selectedCells.push($(this).text());
        });
        // This might not be optimized but it puts evey selected td in your resetted list each time you select
        // By the way, I don't know what you want to put in your list, maybe the index of the td in the table better, I put text
        console.log(selectedCells);
    }
});
```

Comment: OP didn't tag the question with JQuery tho

Comment: although I have never stepped in to the mystified lands of JQuery, I'll try my best to understand the answer by taking some crash course on JQuery :) Will report back for if this works after I try it out.

Comment: After reading a bit in JQuery, my assumption is, this is kinda like using the class marking and getElementByClass method. Sorry Jonas, this is not the answer I am looking for. Perhaps this can solve my problem, if I am just wanting to get my job done, but my main question is "How do I access the marked/focused < td > elements in my < table >, using the mark/focus to access them". Thanks for your answer anyway, but JaromandaX's answer is the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

following the suggestion from JaromandaX, I found a way to access the information I want, here is how, if anyone is interested:

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
const days = [];
for(var i=0; i<selection.rangeCount; i++)
{
    // since I want the value in number representation of day of the month
    days[i] = Number(selection.getRangeAt(i));
}
// from here onward, I can proceed to mark the selected days in my calendar
```